# Django добавить метод к классу django.db.models.Model

Tags: python, django

Как добавить метод к классу django.db.models.Model?
Именно к этому классу, а не к наследованным моделям, чтобы не писать его каждый раз для всех моделей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

правильно:
отнаследовать класс от models.Model, переопределить в нём, что надо и остальные модели наследовать уже от него

как хочешь ты:
заимпортить models.Model, заманкейпатчить другим классом

Comment: спс, сделаю правильно)

Comment: или же можешь создать еще один класс и в нужные модельки его как миксин добавлять